# Need suggestion on how to work with connection polling in java(jsp&servlet)

Tags: jsp, servlets, database-connection, connection-string, connection-pooling

I'm developing a simple project.In this project i'm using n no of jsp pages and servlets to interact with the database. How i have to write the connection string. Presently i written the connection string each and every jsp page.(I knew this is not a best practice). Now my question is how i have to manage the connection string? I have to write in only one common page, then i have to utilize that.. How i can implement this ?? Could any one guide me on this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a JNDI datasource in the servletcontainer. It is by default a connection pooled datasource already. How to do that depends on the servletcontainer make/version. So here's just a Tomcat targeted example:

First create a file `/META-INF/context.xml` (to be clear, the META-INF is at the same level as the WEB-INF of the webapp) and fill it with the following (assuming a MySQL DB).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
    <Resource
        name="jdbc/mydatabase" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" 
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase"
        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        username="java" password="pass"
    />
</Context>
```

Then register it in your webapp's `/WEB-INF/web.xml`.

```
<resource-env-ref>
    <resource-env-ref-name>jdbc/mydatabase</resource-env-ref-name>
    <resource-env-ref-type>javax.sql.DataSource</resource-env-ref-type>
</resource-env-ref>
```

Get it as follows in your DB manager / DAO class.

```
try {
    this.dataSource = (DataSource) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/mydatabase");
} catch (NamingException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("DataSource is missing in JNDI.", e);
}
```

Finally get the connection of it inside the DAO method where you're executing the query.

```
connection = dataSource.getConnection();
```

Don't forget to `close()` it inside the `finally` of the `try` where you're getting it.

#### See also:

- [Basic DAO tutorial](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html#HowAboutConnectionPooling)

Comment: i'm getting the **DataSource is missing in JNDI.** error.. What's the problem ?? Is i have to put any jar files in common lib??

Comment: Then you're not using Tomcat or you've put the files/declarations at wrong places or you didn't understand the example.

Comment: no .. i'm using Tomcat only.. I just created a servlet by using the  eclipse IDE. In the doGet method i just copy and  pasted your code.. And i followed the instructions as per your post!!

Comment: This exception indicates that the datasource is not definied as JNDI resource (i.e. the `META-INF/context.xml` is wrong or missing or the `web.xml` is wrong), or that the JNDI name in Java code is wrong. Which Tomcat version are you using? Following what Servlet version is the web.xml declared?

Comment: Sorry. The problem was in my side. And you are correct, the problem in the context file. It's working now. Could you please tell me totally how many ways to connect with the database? or give me any link.. Thanks for your reply..